# SQL Server Database Connection String & ASP.NET Web Forms (Hosted by Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I have an issue regarding connecting my SQL Server database to my ASP.NET Web Forms website.

So far:

- The SQL Server database is hosted on MS Azure, and I have added a table to it, using MS SQL Server Management  Studio.
- The website is also currently hosted on Azure.

My problem is that I don't know where to place the database's connection string within my project.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG6iB.png) is the connection string in my Azure Portal.

Here are my questions about this:

- Is this the correct connection string I need to read/write from/to the database?
- If this is the right connection string, then where do I place it within my project? Is it within the Web.Config file?
- Finally, I think I need to insert a username and password into this connection string too, where can I find this username?

Comment: You can place the connection string anywhere you want, as long as you can access it where you need it for your SqlConnection, it's just like any other string as far as that is concerned.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, Before trying to host, I was able to use a local database with this connection string in web.config:  **bold**<connectionStrings>
        <add name="FYPConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\FYP.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>**bold**

Comment: @Andrew Do I just need to replace this with the connection string I have posted above in my question? And then just create the connection as usual?

Comment: Yes you could pretty much do that, you then access the connection string the same way you did before. See my answer below for the rest of what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm used to seeing `Data Source=XXX.database.windows.net` everything
   else looks like what I am used to.
2. You can put it anywhere in your project, it's just another string
   that you pass as an argument to SqlConnection.
3. Yes you use a username and password, you would have set that up,
   it's the same one you use for SSMS to connect to that DB.

Comment: <connectionStrings>Server=tcp:damo.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Ballinora_db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30; </connectionStrings>

Comment: Hi @Andrew Does the above seem OK?

Comment: @user7554035 no. `<connectionStrings> <add name="FYPConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=damo.database.windows.net,1433‌​;Initial Catalog=Ballinora_db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveRe‌​sultSets=False;Encry‌​pt=True;TrustServerC‌​ertificate=False;Con‌​nection Timeout=30; /> </connectionStrings>`

Comment: @user7554035 you still need to `<add>` and `name` the setting, you just replace the `connectionString=` part. Plus insert `your_username` and `your_password`

Comment: And then access like this? `static String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FYPConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);`

Comment: @user7554035 exactly, `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` has the code look at your config, `ConnectionStrings` has it look at the connectionStrings section of that config and `[‌​"FYPConnectionString‌​1"]` gets the one named FYPConnectionString‌​1.